# Emacs Scheme buffer taking all CPU resources

Tags: emacs, cpu-usage, resource-usage

I am using Debian Linux Testing. I have installed "Geiser", and when I run Scheme programs (either MIT-Scheme or GNU Scheme) everything is fine. There are no CPU resources used by Emacs during running programs. But when I quit from Emacs, the Scheme programs start to consume all CPU resources (100%). I need to kill the programs by using the "kill" command from the terminal. I wonder how I kill the Geiser Scheme interpreter when I close Emacs.

Comment: Which operating system etc. are you on?  Do you see an "Active processes exist; kill them an exit anyway?" prompt when exiting Emacs?  Tried it on a Mac and it kills the guile process on exit.

Comment: I am using Debian Linux Testing and Emacs 26.1. I see the message "Active processes exist; kill them an exit anyway" and I say "yes".  Somehow it doesn't validate.

Comment: I've only just realised that GNU Scheme != Guile. Took a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/release.html and the first thing there against the 10.1.6 release is "Bug: Killing Emacs *scheme* buffer was not killing the scheme process" which sounds like it could well be the same issue?

Comment: @steevooo, you are right. It is the same issue.